# How can I get a docker container to load text from /etc/motd

Tags: docker

I have a message in /etc/motd and want it to show up every time some one logs into the container  but for some reason it doesn't . What am i missing here ?

Comment: Log in how? SSH? That's not a docker question, that's a Unix/Linux question. This doesn't have anything to do with docker. Also, please be mindful that it's considered bad practice to run an SSH server inside a docker container except in some edge cases. If you mean "login" with something like `nsenter` or the best practice `docker exec`, then that's not really "logging in", and what you want to do is impossible without modifying source.

Comment: There is no magic in docker, do it the same way you would do on any Linux server.

Answer (score 6):

`man motd` says, that:

```
The contents of /etc/motd are displayed by pam_motd(8)
after a successful login but just before it executes the login shell.
```

So technicaly you are missing that PAM module, but since it's a question about Docker, I would highly recomend you not trying to install it. It would be against docker best practices( ["Don’t install unnecessary packages"](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#dont-install-unnecessary-packages) ) . The image must be as thin as possible. Consider using system-wide `/etc/bash.bashrc` adding some `echo`s there. And even if you install `pam_motd`, to see motd you have to exec `login`, not `bash` or any other non-login shell.

All that is correct unless, of course, you develop an image, which main purpose is to display `motd`.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you could add `cat /etc/motd` in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`. Depends on what you mean by "logs into the container".

user2915097 is right: there is no magic in Docker, do as you would on any server.

Comment: +1, I use `echo '[ ! -z "$TERM" -a -r /etc/motd ] && cat /etc/issue && cat /etc/motd' >> /etc/bash.bashrc`. See http://ashgillman.github.io/2015/11/17/Docker-MOTD.html